# how to add new line while sending sms using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is My code
  I am trying to add new line

```
 $textmsg=' Name-'.$this->session->userdata['data']['dname'].
          'Seat No-'.$this->session->userdata['data']['fs'].
          $this->session->userdata['data']
          ['ss'].$this->session->userdata['data']['ts'].
          'Mobile :-'.$this->session->userdata['data']['mobile'];
```

Comment: Yes, and now what?

Comment: it showing like, seate:-\n1, its printing \n also

Comment: I don't see any `\n` here. But my bets are on `\n` or `\r\n` as a newline

Comment: am betting you are doing `'\n'` rather than in double quotes. Yet, you (may) want `<br>` if to be echo'd on screen.

Comment: I used "\n" its working fine thanks

Comment: @YogeshJamkar welcome; I posted an answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/43426401/1415724 that if you want to, mark it as solved in order to close the question properly and that everyone will know it was solved

Answer (score 2):

Just as I stated in comments; you were most likely using `\n` inside single quotes `'\n'`.

Those will not get parsed; you need to use `\n` inside double quotes.

I.e.: `"\n"`.

Add that to the areas of your code that you wish to have new lines.

Depending on the OS this is running under, you can use:

- `"\r\n"` on Windows
- `PHP_EOL` cross platform predefined constant
  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php.

The `\n` is for *NIX platforms.

Answer (score -1):

If your sms gateway doesn't support new line you can't send it. Actually your problem is just add "\n" character. Which sms operator are you using?